# How to get rid of ScalalikeJDBC implicit DBSession argument in my DAO trait methods?

Tags: scala, inheritance, dao, implicit

According to the [ScalalikeJDBC documentation](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/auto-session.html), it is encouraged to use an implicit `DBSession` argument on one's DAO methods:

```scala
def findById(id: Long)(implicit session: DBSession) =
    sql"select id, name from members where id = ${id}"
        .map(rs => Member(rs)).single.apply()
```

Thing is, the DAO pattern dictates an interface/trait along with the implementation, but with ScalalikeJDBC I need to "dirty" my trait with the implicit argument (which is completely irrelevant to my other implementations).

Anyway around this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, to make your DAO interface universal, you have to somehow move session from method params into method body:

```
def findById(id: Long) = {
    implicit val session = SessionManager.getSession()
    sql"select id, name from members where id = ${id}"
        .map(rs => Member(rs)).single.apply()
}
```

All you need now, is to properly implement SessionManager =) or you can use `AutoSession`:

```
def findById(id: Long) = {
    implicit val session = AutoSession
    sql"select id, name from members where id = ${id}"
        .map(rs => Member(rs)).single.apply()
}
```

Comment: I'm not interested in implementing a `SessionManager` :) Can I simply assign `AutoSession` into that variable?

Comment: I've just realized that's not a good solution; it means the method will always use an `AutoSession` (no way of invoking it with something else). Sure, you can still go ahead and implement a `SessionManager` of a sort, but that kind of defeats the purpose of this utility (and employs a singleton).

Comment: Also, `AutoSession` is a very confusing name; it implies that this `DBSession` object can magically find the current existing session, and if it doesn't find one it will create a new one. No, it simply creates a new transaction. The "auto" feature is implemented by merely overriding that variable when calling the method (so, in fact, you no longer use the `AutoSession` object).